# How to store the time data in a timer program

Tags: java, xml, swing, filesystems, data-storage

I have a program in Java Swing that has stop and start buttons that track the time that passed since the start button was pressed and display it via `JLabel`. What I want to do now is to store the time in some way. But I'm not sure how to go about this. Should I store it in a `.txt`, `.ini` or `.xml` file? Or use some other file type? The data to be stored includes time: pairs d:m:y and [h:m:s, h:m:s].

Comment: *Should I store it in a .txt, .ini or .xml file? Or use some other file type?*  **yes** why does it matter?

Comment: @Scary Wombat To be able to parse it more easily. To know what the common practice is.

Comment: how does the file type make it easier to parse?

Comment: @Scary Wombat Because there are existing libraries for some of the types?

Comment: In that case go for java properties file

Comment: You can also just used the classes XMLEncoder and XMLDecoder which write and read serializable objects in a xml file